# Google OAuth components must be used within GoogleOAuthProvider

Tags: reactjs, next.js, google-oauth

I want to build my next js project in which i am using
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-oauth/google
but when I build it i get the following :
[image]

[image]

this is layout.js and in _app.js I have all the components wrapped in GoogleOAuthProvider

```
import { GoogleLogin } from '@react-oauth/google';
import {FcGoogle} from "react-icons/Fc"
import { useGoogleLogin } from '@react-oauth/google';
export default function Layout({ children }) {
    const client_id = ""
    const responseGoogle = (response) => {
        console.log(response);
    }
CUTTED (NOT RELEVANT)
    const login = useGoogleLogin({
        onSuccess: codeResponse => {

            const { code } = codeResponse;
            console.log(codeResponse)
            axios.post("http://localhost:8080/api/create-tokens", {  code }).then(response => {
                const { res, tokens } = response.data;
                const refresh_token = tokens["refresh_token"];
                const db = getFirestore(app)
                updateDoc(doc(db, 'links', handle), {
                    refresh_token : refresh_token
                })
                updateDoc(doc(db, 'users', useruid), {
                    refresh_token : refresh_token
                }).then(
CUTTED (NOT RELEVANT)
                )
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err.message);

            })
        },
        onError: errorResponse => console.log(errorResponse),
        flow: "auth-code",
        scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"
    });
    return (
        <>
CUTTED (NOT RELEVANT)

        </>
    )
}
```

Everything works perfect in dev mode but it does not want to build

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've faced this issue too. So I use 'GoogleLogin' instead of 'useGoogleLogin', then you can custom POST method on 'onSuccess' property.

```
    import { GoogleLogin, GoogleOAuthenProvider} from '@react-oauth/google';
    import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode';

    return(
        <GoogleOAuthProvider clientId="YOUR CLIENT ID">
            <GoogleLogin
                onSuccess={handleLogin}
            />
        </GoogleOAuthProvider>
```

The async function will be like...

```js
    const handleLogin = async (credentialResponse) => {
        var obj = jwtDecode(credentialResponse.credential);
        var data = JSON.stringify(obj);
        console.log(data);

        const data = {your data to send to server};

        const config = {
          method: 'POST',
          url: 'your backend server or endpoint',
          headers: {},
          data: data
        }

      await axios(config)
    }
```

Spending whole day, this solve me out. Just want to share.

Comment: Haha didn't believed anyone was gonna respond to it after 2 months.

Comment: I've been working a new project, some npm doesn't work. Google just update a new Identity service, that's why this npm has bug.

Comment: @hhelsinki There's no option to define required scopes when using these components whereas there was an option in hook to define scopes.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap your application within `GoogleOAuthProvider` component. Please keep in mind that you will need your client ID for this.

```
import { GoogleOAuthProvider } from '@react-oauth/google';

<GoogleOAuthProvider clientId="<your_client_id>">
    <SomeComponent />
    ...
    <GoogleLoginButton onClick={handleGoogleLogin}/>
</GoogleOAuthProvider>;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error because I was using a custom google login button. It got resolved once I wrapped the the whole app component inside `GoogleOAuthProvider` component instead of wrapping just the custom button component.

```
\\ App.js

import {GoogleOAuthProvider} from '@react-oauth/google';

<GoogleOAuthProvider clientId="YOURCLIENT_ID">
    <App/>
</GoogleOAuthProvider>;
```

Answer (score 0):

The *GoogleOAuthenProvider* is supposed to wrap your whole application I guess, as the creator of the package does it. You won't have these errors again.

So, include it to your **index.js** file

```
import { GoogleOAuthProvider } from '@react-oauth/google';
....
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <GoogleOAuthProvider clientId="304531247476-58f940f3b0dgrupg95cdo8b51fspupdv.apps.googleusercontent.com">
      <ChakraProvider>
        <App />
      </ChakraProvider>
    </GoogleOAuthProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
);
```

---

Similarly, if you were to follow [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/client-library), you would have to include the below code to your  in public/index.html

```
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async></script>
```